# Forbidden 403 for Codeigniter url without % encoded (%25)

Tags: apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-403

I moved my website developed with Codeigniter 3.1.13 to a server with Apache 2.4.52 on Ubuntu (previously it was Apache 2.4.6 on Centos).

Now when a url contains an encoded character with % (i.e. a whitespace as %20) I received this error message:

> Forbidden
> You don't have permission to access this resource.

The only workaround is to encode the % character as well, with the code %25. So whitespace becomes %2520.

Here's my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

#Lime Rules
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) "/lime.php?/$1" [L]
RewriteRule ^admin$ /lime.php?/ [L]

#Codeigniter Rules
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|lime\.php|assets|images|uploads|phpMyAdmin|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Custom Rules
RewriteRule ^assets/lime/css_to_parse/(.*)$ /admin/lime/parser_css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^assets/website/css_to_parse/(.*)$ /head/parser_css/$1 [L]
```

What's the proper way to solve the problem?